# Assigning IP addresses to multiple nightly k8s clusters

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Background:
We run Analytics pipelines on dedicated clusters once a day. All clusters are created at the same time, have once pod deployed, run their pipeline and are deleted once complete, use the default VPC network in the same region and are created with a command like this:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create <CLUSTER_NAME> \
    --zone "europe-west1-b" \
    --machine-type "n1-standard-2" \
    --num-nodes=1 \
    --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
    --service-account=<SA_EMAIL> \
    --disk-size 10GB \
    --network default \
    --subnetwork <SUB_NETWORK> \
    --enable-master-global-access \
    --enable-private-nodes \
    --enable-private-endpoint \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --enable-intra-node-visibility \
    --enable-master-authorized-networks \
    --master-ipv4-cidr=<MASTER_IP>/28 \
    --cluster-ipv4-cidr <CLUSTER_IP>/14 \
    --services-ipv4-cidr <SERVICES_IP/20 \
    --enable-network-policy \
    --enable-shielded-nodes
```

When we add a new cluster for a new pipeline we have encountered issues where the IP addresses collide, overlap and are unavailable. As we expect to continually add more pipelines and thus more clusters we want an automated way of avoiding this issue.

We have explored creating a dedicated network (and subnetwork) for each cluster so each cluster can have the same IP addresses (albeit in different networks) but are unsure if this is best practice.

Question:
Is it possible to create kubernetes clusters in Google Cloud so as the master, cluster and service IP addresses are auto-assigned?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your use case e.g. why you are using VPC-native cluster ?

Comment: @mario I don't really have more info (due to lack of knowledge). The above command is how we were told to create clusters to ensure their security was sufficient. What other options do we have instead of VPC-native clusters? I am aware of routes-based clusters however the docs say VPC-native is the recommended type: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/routes-based-cluster#:~:text=Google%20Kubernetes%20Engine.-,Overview,called%20a%20VPC%2Dnative%20cluster..